# R Focal Function - Terra vs Raster

Tags: raster, r, terra, focal-statistics

I'm not sure why the focal function I've been using in Raster does not work with Terra.  This simplified example uses a custom function to apply the focal filter only to pixels with a value of 0 and it "grows" the pixels out to neighboring pixels (rooks case)....It works with raster, but I get the following message when attempting in Terra:  Error:  [Focal] test failed

```
library(raster)
tmpRas = raster(matrix(c(1:14,0,16:36,6,6))
plot(tmpRas)
```

[image]

```
grow0 = function(x){if (0%in%x){return(0)} else {return(x[5])}
w=matrix(c(NA,1,NA,1,1,1,NA,1,NA),3,3)
FocalRas = focal(tmpRas, w, fun = grow0, pad=TRUE, padValue = 1)
plot(FocalRas)
```

[image]

Any ideas on why this same method does not work with Terra, or is there an easier way to do what I'm trying to accomplish?  Here is the same workflow using Terra:

```
library(terra)
tmpRast = rast(matrix(c(1:14,0,16:36),6,6)
FocalRast = focal(tmpRast, w, fun = grow0)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example worked for me using:

```
library(terra)

tmpRast = rast(matrix(c(1:14,0,16:36),6,6)) # terra spatRaster object

grow0 = function(x){if (0%in%x){return(0)} else {return(x[5])}}
w=matrix(c(NA,1,NA,1,1,1,NA,1,NA),3,3)

FocalRast = terra::focal(tmpRast, w, fun = grow0) # terra::focal
plot(FocalRast)
```

It was only necessary to fix some minor bugs in the code. I also added `terra::focal` so that I used the function from the terra package. I'm not sure, but it's probably more efficient than `raster::focal`.

If it still doesn't work for you update your terra package to:

```
terra version 1.4.11
```

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful to know it was working for someone else!  I was still getting the same error but now it works after updating my Terra package

Comment: @EricJeronimus: That's why it is a good idea to make use of `{reprex}` when creating minimal reproducing examples. After `library(terra)` you would have posted automatically `terra 1.2.13` or some other outdated version - and everyone would have suggested to first update your package.. :)